# more columns or one array, what is better performance?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a game(minecraft) region database and player's permissions.
and these are my table ideas.

## example1)

**Column ---------------- Datatype**
worldname ------------ 1 ----- (INT(10)) ----- PK , NN
regionname ----------- 1 ----- (INT(10)) ----- PK , NN
owner ------------------- 2 ----- (INT(10))
member ---------------- 5, 13, 54, 246, 38295, 564, 2535, 5364, 411, 9 ----- (VARCHAR(128))


this one and I receive 'member' and split by ', ' to array.

## example2)

**Column ---------------- Datatype**
worldname ------------ 1 ----- (INT(10)) ----- PK , NN
regionname ----------- 1 ----- (INT(10)) ----- PK , NN
owner ------------------- 2 ----- (INT(10)
member1 -------------- 5 ----- (INT(10))
member2 -------------- 13 ----- (INT(10))
member3 -------------- 54 ----- (INT(10))
member4 -------------- 246 ----- (INT(10))
member5 -------------- 38295 ----- (INT(10))
member6 -------------- 564 ----- (INT(10))
member7 -------------- 2535 ----- (INT(10))
member8 -------------- 5364 ----- (INT(10))
member9 -------------- 411 ----- (INT(10))
member10 ------------- 9 ----- (INT(10))

## which one is better performance?

Comment: (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neither!

The best practice is to create three separate tables which one holds user data, one holds your worlds and the last one, holds relation between these two tables.

So table 1:
`world`
columns:
`id`
`name`
`region`
`owner`
.
.
.

table2 :
`user`
 columns:
`id`
`username`
.
.
.

table3:
`world_user`
 columns:
`world_id`
`user_id`
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you want to do. If a new player registers, a new member is created?

But if number of member is fix you should take the second option. A database is made for search in and do some request. However, a loop in any language (ie PHP) is slow.

I hope it will helps,
Best regards !

Comment: no It's user tradable zone's name, world name and zone name is the primary key. and the zone has 'who is owner' & 'who are members'. sometimes the zone has no owner, and no members.